# My viewport result and render result is deferent

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, lighting, light-groups

[image]

This is my viewport display. I am checking if any object is hidden, but there is no problem.

[image]

I am using a black principle shader for light blocking.
I want that dark part in my result. but there are some lights in my render.

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: File size larger than 30 Mb.

Comment: use another platform like workupload for example